# Fully elastic header-body-footer based on CSS table implementation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a generic header-body-footer section which is fully stretched based on the dimensions (width+height) of its outer div. An example on this approach:

**CSS**

```
    .outer
    {
        position:relative;
        width:200px; 
        height:150px;
        border:1px dotted black;
        margin:-1px;
    }
    .tbl
    {
        display:table; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%;
    }
    .tr
    {
        display:table-row;
    }
    .td
    {
        display:table-cell; 
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center; 
    }
    .body-outer
    {
        position:relative;
        height:100%; 
        width:100%; 
    }
    .body-inner
    {
         position:absolute; 
         top:0; 
         right:0; 
         bottom:0; 
         left:0; 
         overflow-y:auto; 
         overflow-x:auto;
    }
    .stretch-x
    {
        width:100%;
    }
    .stretch-y
    {
        height:100%;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="tbl">
    <div class="tr" style="background-color:Red;">
        <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tr stretch-y" style="background-color:Gray;">
        <div class="td stretch-y" style="background-color:Blue;">
            <div class="body-outer" style="background-color:Green;">
                <div class="body-inner">
                <p style=" white-space:nowrap;">test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
                <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr" style="background-color:Red;">
        <p>test paragraph. This is used as placeholder<br />new line....</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything is working as expected in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera. But not in IE... even in IE10. The problem is that IE doesn't identify the height of the "body" section as relative to its ancestor "td" and calculates the respected height as relative to the "outer" div. Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the mystery has been solved... The IE should run under Quirks mode (!!!!) in order to be compliant with common standards!!!

The above design constitutes a fully elastic header-body-footer section based on CSS table implementation. You may use it in case that:

1. You have concrete dimensions of the outer box (even using percentage and following the known constraints concerning parent container height etc...)
2. You want everything inside the outer box be elastic and auto-stretched

A fully working example @jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92y9L/9/

```
see code above (↑)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall with this for the past few days, trying all manner of hacks to get it to work. This does indeed solve the issue. Unfortunately, for my particular use case I don't think quirks mode is acceptable. What could be achieved in pure CSS may need some help from JavaScript, which always makes me feel a little dirty.